# How to remain in session after exiting tailf command from remote script

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, tail

Have PowerShell script from which I am executing the following command: `putty.exe -ssh user@srv -pw password -m Execute_Command_File -t`

During the script, `tailf /dir/log/` command is written into Execute_Command_File. After executing the script, requested session is opened and `tailf` is working.

The problem, when I trying to exit from `tailf`(ctrl+C), it closes the terminal.

Tried to add `/bin/bash` at the end of `Execute_Command_File`, not helping. And of course tried `tail -f/F`, also not working...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that `tail` dies because of the CTRL+C but it is also sent (SINGINT) to the parent, `bash`. Since by default bash dies when receive such signal, you have to replace the default behavior of `bash` when receives it.

Use **trap** built-in command of `bash(1)` to change this.

Following script `tailf-ctrl.sh`  is a demo and shows the answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
function finish {
    echo "CTRL-C pressed!"
}

F=testfile

echo hello > $F
# set custom action
trap finish SIGINT # comment this to see the problem
tail -f $F
# reset default action
trap - SIGINT

echo "Hello after" > after
cat after
```

note that:

1. **SIGINT** is the signal related to CTRL+C
2. first **trap** install a custom action related to the SIGINT signal
3. second **trap** reset default behavoir of the SIGINT signal

Output of the script is:

```
$ bash tailf-ctrl.sh 
hello
^CCTRL-C pressed!
Hello after
```

that shows that the second file is written so the end of script is reached when `tail` dies because of the `CTRL-C`.

if you comment out the first trap command, you see your problem appears: bash immediately terminates and the output should be:

```
$ bash tailf-ctrl.sh 
hello
^C
$
```

Comment: Worked as expected, thx. Wasn't familiar with `trap`, seems to be very useful